# Is it possible to configure Jackson ObjectMapper to always use @JsonIdentityInfo

Tags: configuration, jackson, objectmapper

I understand that I can control the behavior of Jackson's ObjectMapper to include information about the identity of objects using the @JsonIdentityInfo annotation on a class.

Is it possible to achieve this by configuring the ObjectMapper itself to include type identity information for every object?

Is there a reason why the ObjectMapper should not be configured in this way (i.e. if there is no way to do this, is there a good reason for that)?

Comment: Thanks @MichałZiober for responding.  I know about the default typing feature.  That's not what I am asking about here.

Comment: I have the same problem